# Effect of R/S configuration on reactions not involving the stereocentre

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity, stereochemistry

An exam question involved the following reaction -

[image] + [image] forms [image]

Both reactants (2-methylbutanoic acid and 2-methylbutanamine) are optically active. The question used pure R-enantiomer of the acid, and a racemic mixture of the amine, amine in excess.

However, it also suggested that the R isomer of acid **will not** react equally well with both enantiomers of the amine. I could not understand why, since the reaction does not involve any stereocentre. My best (and probably silly) guess would be that one configuration would encounter greater steric hindrance during attack of the nitrogen atom on carbon, so that product will be formed less. However, I could not find any resource to support this, nor did I find this very likely as the tertiary carbon atoms are separated by 4 bonds - so steric hindrance probably won't have a large effect.

Could anyone please confirm if the configuration does indeed affect the reactivity, and if yes, how and why?

Comment: The effect might be very small. but it's definitely nonzero.

Comment: @orthocresol But what is the reason for that effect? Is it steric hindrance, as I proposed?

Comment: What are the reaction conditions?

Comment: @Waylander Only these reactants are given, nothing else is mentioned (that same exam where students are expected to know everything by telepathy), but amide was the intended product - I'm sure of that.

Comment: @Waylander Also, this is just a specific example I encountered - my question is about the general case. If R/S might affect reactivity during formation of esters or ethers or secondary amines as well, apart from amides as above.

Comment: The only reason I can think of given the paucity of information on the reaction conditions is that the reaction of one enantiomer is slightly more hindered than the other

Comment: The bottom line is that it will be different, simply because the products and transition states are diastereomeric. Thus, there’s no way it can be *exactly* the same. Having a model or a rationale to understand which one is faster is nice, but secondary: you must first accept that they are different.

Comment: @orthocresol I see now - two diastereomers are inherently different in other properties than optical rotation, too. I was mainly thinking about the two individual molecules. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: If you got your answer, feel free to self-answer it :)

Comment: @NilayGhosh Done :) I still don't have a source though, nor a model/theory that can reasonably predict which one out of the two products will be favoured. If you have any resources regarding that, it'll be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @orthocresol for helping me via the comments. Here is a reasonable explanation for it -

The final product comprises of two different **diastereomers**, of configurations *RR* and *RS*. Diastereomers, unlike enantiomers, have some *inherently* different properties, other than optical rotation.

Consequently, the reaction that forms two different diastereomers will proceed through intermediates and transition states that will also have different properties. Since they differ in aspects other than optical rotation, their products will be formed in different amounts. Just because the products **are** different, the amounts formed are also bound to be different - they essentially become two different reactions. Even if the difference is very slight.